# tunnel playback using hardware decoder

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I tried the video playback through Exo-player. I have made changes in the exo-player code to support tunneling mode as suggested in the below link.

https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/tunneled-video-playback-in-exoplayer-84f084a8094d

I have added hardware decoder support in the media_codec.xml file. I have also included the tunneling feature in the xml file as mentioned below.

Feature name="tunneled-playback" required="true"/>

Once i enable the "tunneled-playback" feature, the player is making use of software video decoder.

Even after all the changes, software decoder is being used.
Can someone suggest me how to make use of hardware decoder with the tunneled-playback feature?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of steps you can do:

1. Make sure that tunnelling is supported by your platform, setting the feature only will not suffice.
2. Ensure that the tunnelled codec is selected. what Exo does is to query the list of codecs and pick the first one as the most preferable. Some platform does not list the tunnelled codec first, therefore it's not picked.
3. Check if an audio session ID is actually created. Failure in creating the audio session ID would prevent tunnelled playback.